# Display Rails3 Flash messages between format.html and format.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to share FlashHash notices more cleanly between plain-old HTTP users and UJS folks that I've been able to contrive. Allow me to show you what I have first:

First, part of the `respond_to` section of the relevant controller's `#update`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @cont.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Continent was successfully updated.'
    format.html { redirect_to edit_continent_url(@cont) }
    format.json { head :ok }
    format.js
```

and an `update.js.erb` to match it:

```
$('#jsflash').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "application/notices/notice") %>').show();
<% flash.clear %> # clear the flash to avoid displaying on page reloads
```

Likewise in my `application.html.erb` there is

```
<div id="jsflash"></div>
<%= render "application/notice/alert" %>
```

and `app/views/application/notices/_notice.html.erb`:

```
<% unless flash[:notice].blank? %>
  <div class="alert-message info fade in" data-alert="alert">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <%= content_tag :p, flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

### Things I don't like:

1. Maybe it's anal, but I would prefer to not render `<div id="jsflash"></div>` unless I absolutely have to.
2. The `<% flash.clear %>` in the update js exists to clear flash out in case of page reload. However, that's going to get really tedious and error-prone as each JS view will need to have this *but* might forget to include it.
3. The `<% flash.clear %>`, likewise, it's a confusion of roles, with the view driving application state.
4. It seems like there should be some facility for this already. Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To avoid rendering `<div id="jsflash"></div>` when its not needed you will want to wrap the flash block in an if statement. You could put something like this in your `Application.rb`

.

```
 <% if flash.present? %>
   //Call your Render Flash Here
 <% end %>
```

2.3.4. I've never had to use `flash.clear` in the dozens of flash applications I have made. You also seem to have some unneeded duplication here with your flash calls.

Comment: "You also seem to have some unneeded duplication here with your flash calls." Can you elaborate on this? I've almost exclusively built API-only affairs.

Comment: I meant to say that I am unsure as to why you are setting up your flash message in your application.rb through a call to a partial and also through your update.js. When I run something similar in my test app for this, the jQuery call simply overwrites what was already there by the render call in application.rb. Perhaps I am not understanding the logic behind the js in this case.

Comment: Largely inexperience with non-API applications, I'd say. Thanks!